# Transferring car titles between states

Tags: vehicle, ohio, virginia

Just moved to Virginia from Ohio, already have a job, and trying to go through the steps [here](http://www.dmv.org/va-virginia/new-to-virginia.php).

I have a car right now, but my mom has the title, and she lives in Ohio. We are trying to transfer the title to me, with the least amount of fees.

I've found [this](http://www.dmvnow.com/webdoc/pdf/sut3.pdf) form, which would appear to tell me I can transfer the car between mother to son without any taxes. However I cannot find any equivalent form in Ohio and I don't know how I can go about transferring the vehicle at all.

Here's one potential solution I was thinking of:
Could my mom sell the vehicle to me out of state using the instruction on the  Ohio DMV (I would post the link here, however "You need at least 10 reputation to post more than 2 links")? However, if I do, don't I need to prove that I paid taxes on it while in Virgina? If so how complicated is that process?

To summarize my question is:

1. How can I obtain the vehicle from my mom while paying the least amount of state taxes/fees, under the time constraint of about a week?

Or

2. If this isn't the right place to ask this, where can I go to get direction. I am very, very lost in this, and the more I read, honestly the more confused I am. Transferring between states is hard!